# Multiple email accounts from the same server in Emacs Gnus

Tags: emacs, gnus

I'm trying to set up Gnus to use both my gmail accounts but I can only ever get one at a time to show up in the list of folders.

```
(setq gnus-select-method '(nnimap "work@mywork.org"
                            (nnimap-address "secure.emailsrvr.com")
                            (nnimap-server-port 993)
                            (nnimap-stream ssl)))

(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods
      '((nnimap "myfirstaddress@gmail.com"
                (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
                (nnimap-server-port 993)
                (nnimap-stream ssl))
        (nnimap "mysecondaddress@gmail.com"
                (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
                (nnimap-server-port 993)
                (nnimap-stream ssl))))
```

That is the relevant portions of my .gnus file. It prompts me for three username passwords on startup. After I enter all three, I can access my work account and the gmail account that I enter the creds for second. This is really annoying! Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 'foreign' servers instead of secondary servers.  I have gnus set up as follows:

```
(setq gnus-select-method '(nntp "127.0.0.1"))
```

To set up the foreign server, go to your Gnus Group buffer and hit the '^' key to go to the server list.  Here you can add a new "server", which can be an alias for a real server, by hitting 'a'.  For example, I have a server defined with the following attributes:

```
(nnimap "foobar"
    (nnimap-address "192.168.1.101")
    (nnimap-server-port 143)
    (nnimap-list-pattern
     ("INBOX" "*"))
    (nnimap-stream network)
    (nnimap-authenticator login)
    (nnimap-authinfo-file "~/.authinfo")
    (nnimap-expunge-on-close always)
    (gnus-check-new-newsgroups nil))
```

I can add a second one, with similar attributes:

```
(nnimap "baz"
    (nnimap-address "192.168.1.101")
    (nnimap-server-port 143)
    (nnimap-list-pattern
     ("INBOX" "*"))
    (nnimap-stream network)
    (nnimap-authenticator login)
    (nnimap-expunge-on-close never)
    (nnimap-authinfo-file "~/.authinfo")
    (gnus-check-new-newsgroups nil))
```

in my `~/.authinfo` file I have:

```
machine baz login bazzy.mcbaz force yes port 143
machine foobar login foobar password FooB@r force yes port 143
```

So one of them has the password and one doesn't.  Also, the `authinfo` file defines what the login ID is.

Comment: Where you say "For example, I have a server defined with the following attributes:" can you be more specific. Where have you defined these and using what list?

Comment: @richard: while on the screen where you went with ^, hit e. You'd be given the chance to set-up the server. Just make sure you never delete .newsrc.eld because changes are saved there.

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for my delay in answering.)  It seems the accepted answer doesn't solve the problem of saving both passwords.  That seems a limitation of `~/.authinfo` which stores the passwords.  To get around that, create different hostnames and use your `hosts` file to point to the same gmail host.  For example:

```
machine imap.gmail1.com login sunda@gmail.com password soup
machine smtp.gmail1.com login sunda@gmail.com 587 password soup

machine imap.gmail2.com login sunda2@gmail.com password soup2
machine smtp.gmail2.com login sunda2@gmail.com 587 password soup2
```

Notice that this also frees you from using foreign servers, since GNUS will consider gmail1.com as one source and gmail2.com as another source.

Here's how your set up can be:

```
(setq gnus-select-method '(nntp "news.server.some.where"))
(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods 
      '((nnimap "imap.gmail1.com"
                (nnimap-address "imap.gmail1.com")
                (nnimap-server-port 993)
                (nnimap-stream ssl))
        (nnimap "imap.gmail2.com"
                (nnimap-address "imap.gmail2.com")
                (nnimap-server-port 993)
                (nnimap-stream ssl))
        ))
```

Answer (score 1):

i managed to do this by using 2 different `.authinfo` files like this:

```
(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods
      '((nnimap "myfirstaddress@gmail.com"
                (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
                (nnimp-authinfo-file ".authinfo_one")
                (nnimap-server-port 993)
                (nnimap-stream ssl))
        (nnimap "mysecondaddress@gmail.com"
                (nnimap-address "imap.gmail.com")
                (nnimp-authinfo-file ".authinfo_two")
                (nnimap-server-port 993)
                (nnimap-stream ssl))))
```

The two `.authinfo` files then feature the **same host**, but different username/passwords:

```
machine imap.gmail.com login user1 password "password1"
```